# Database design for Django review website

Tags: python, django, database-design

Hi I'm developing a review site for learning Django.

Every review has a list of rating attributes like:

- Price: **[x] [x] [x] [x] [x]**
- Location: **[x] [x] [ ] [ ] [ ]**
- Comfort: **[x] [x] [x] [ ] [ ]**
- etc.

I'm stuck at the point of writing the review/rating model. How can I describe this with MVC pattern? The list of rating attributes can be different.

Currently I've this code:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

class Review(models.Model):
    ????

class Review(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    place = models.ForeignKey(place)
    ratings = models.ForeignKey(Rating)
```

Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure there is no list of possible attributes available in the first place? You could then just introduce a database field for each of them.

Comment: The attribute list can be different relying on what type is the Place.  However what you suggest for creating the rating model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list of (potential) attributes is available beforehand, you can just introduce a database field for each of them and store not-set attributes as `None`:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    place = models.ForeignKey(place)

    price_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    location_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    # ...
```

Otherwise (if the attributes/ratings are totally variable), you have to create another model to store your attributes (drop the `_rating` fields above then):

```
class ReviewAttribute(models.Model):
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, related_name='attributes')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In your opinion is a good way to create a `ReviewAttribute` for saving all rating of all reviews? It not overloads the database with thousands of rows?

Comment: That really depends... as I said, if possible I would try to restrict the set of potential attributes and create corresponding fields. Otherwise, you could just store all attributes in a single `TextField` using some minimal markup (e.g. "Field1:1;Field2:3"); however, this violates the atomic database design principle. Just for retrieving reviews and their attributes it's certainly faster, but on the other hand it doesn't allow you to filter based on review attributes etc. on the database level, which might be crucial for you.

Comment: Also, with something like a review, you're not likely to introduce many complicated relationships. This will keep your searches fast, up into the millions.

Comment: What do you mean for "atomic database design principle"? I'm a beginner, sorry if is an straightforward question :) By the way I get your point. I know also the database are done for this matter and is normal that they contains thousands and millions of rows, but I've a question just-for-curiosity: in your opinion, with a standard database like PostgreSQL or MySQL, what is the rows limit after that I can feel a substantial slowdown of queries?

Comment: @Droogans you think that also if I use `ReviewAttribute` class for attributes? It is not a complicated relationship?

Comment: By "atomic design" I mean that you should not store several "values" (such as several review attributes) in one database field. Don't worry about the resulting number of rows — as you said, relational databases are meant to be used that way. If you have the proper indices (Django will create the most important ones on the foreign keys, of course) and use proper queries (e.g. consider using Django's all-new `prefetch_related`), thousands of rows will be no problem at all, and millions should still work, too.

Comment: `Review` abstracts the contents of itself (this is stored in `ReviewAttribute`). If you were to, say, differentiate between many *types* of reviews, and each had its own foreign key, it would slow down. As a rule, the more foreign keys you have, and the more joins you use to get data, the slower your database will respond.

Comment: Yes, I get it Droogans. Probably in my case I need to use `ReviewAttribute` for the reasons I said before. Thank you for your help :)